# How can I automatically apply env variables to the 'npm install' process?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there any way I can setup environment variables in `package.json` that will apply to the npm install process, without first setting them in my shell?

My use case is installing `puppeteer` - it uses a variable `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD`. However, I don't want my team to have to set that manually each time they start work. Is there any way I can set that up to apply whenever I run `npm install` or `yarn`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out you can just set `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true` in `.npmrc`!

Comment: Refer to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431439/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-to-be-used-during-npm-install#comment130415527_60172169